# Let $a$,$b$,$c$ be real numbers.

Tags: inequality

Let $a$,$b$,$c$ be real numbers such that $a^{4}+b^{4}+c^{4}\leq27$. Prove the inequality:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^{2}+1}}\geq \frac{3}{2}$$

My solution:
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^{2}+1}}\geq\frac{1}{2}\implies a^{2}\leq 3\implies a^{4}\leq 9$.
Similary : $b^{4}\leq9$ and $c^{4}\leq9$.
Then $a^{4}+b^{4}+c^{4}\leq27$ which is obviously true.

My solution is good ?

Comment: Looks like you're on the right track, but you're working backwards. Your goal should be to end with the cyclic sum, not to end with the given constraint.

Comment: Also note that it isn't necessarily true that all three of $a^4, b^4, c^4$ are less than or equal to $9$. Given $x+y+z \ge \frac32$, we can conclude that *at least* one of $x,y,z$ is greater than or equal to $\frac12$, but not that all of them are.

Comment: You also don't know that $\frac1{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\ge \frac12$, only that the sum is greater than $\frac32$

Comment: The problem in your solution is that $a^4+b^4+c^4\leq 27$ doesn't mean $a^4\leq 9, b^4\leq 9, c^4\leq 9$. Take $a=b=1.8, c=1$, for example.

Comment: any solution ??

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_a = \sqrt{a^2 + 1}$, and similarly for $x_b$ and $x_c$. Then by RMS-HM inequality on $x_a, x_b, x_c$,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{3}{x_a^{-1}+x_b^{-1}+x_c^{-1}}
&\le \sqrt{\frac{x_a^2+x_b^2+x_c^2}3} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{(a^2+1)+(b^2+1)+(c^2+1)}3}\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}3 + 1}\tag1\\
\end{align*}$$

By RMS-AM inequality on $a^2,b^2,c^2$,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}3
&\le \sqrt{\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}3}\\
&\le \sqrt{\frac{27}3}\\
&= 3\tag2\\
\end{align*}$$

Combining results $(1)$ and $(2)$,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{3}{x_a^{-1}+x_b^{-1}+x_c^{-1}} &\le \sqrt{3+1}\\
\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+1}} &\ge \frac{3}{2}\\
\end{align*}$$